# Systemd: Autostart service after mongodb

Tags: 16.04, services, autostart, mongodb

ubuntu16.04.1, systemd

An application depends on mongodb. The application and mongodb both start on boot as services. `app.service` containts next line:

```
After=network.target mongod.service
```

Unfortunately, the application fails (with connection to database error), I guess, because the mongodb needs some time to startup and be ready to connections (if I start the app later, everything is ok).

It looks like `Type=notify` (in `[Service]` section of `mongod.service`) will solve the problem if mongodb sends apropriate notification to systemd. But I did not find any documentation about it.

The queston is, how to autostart the application, after mongodb will be ready for incoming connections.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I found this solution to work: https://gist.github.com/jwilm/5842956#gistcomment-2706797

That way mongodb blocks until the database is reachable before systemd starts the next service.

> If you have services that depend on mongodb, the config is slightly
>   more difficult because the default mongodb service returns before the
>   database is online. That can cause quick applications to try and fail
>   to connect to the database. To prevent this, add the following to
>   `/etc/mongod.conf`:
>
> ```
> processManagement:
>     fork: true
> ```
>
> Next, create `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/mongod.conf` (which
>   extends the existing `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`) with the
>   following content:
>
> ```
> [Service]
> Type=oneshot
> RemainAfterExit=yes
> ```
>
> That causes `sudo systemctl start mongod` to start the server in a
>   forked process and return only AFTER the database is up and ready for
>   connections. This way, dependent services only get invoked after the
>   db is live.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this question is already at serverfault. In short: maybe you should use `Requires` instead of `After`.
`Requires` means that your service requires the other to work properly, not that is should "just be started after".

https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires